# How do I capture arguments from npx commands?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npx

I am trying to capture arguments from npx commands in my code.
`npx <package-name> <app-name>`
In the code snippet above, i want to capture the app name when i execute this command.
I am passing the npx command in the `bin` key in the `package.json`.
How do i get the `app-name` when i run the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your package is a Node.js script (which is usually is), the command line arguments are available in [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv). If you only care about the first thing (`app-name` in your example), you can use `process.argv[2]`. (Element 0 in the array will be the executable name and element 1 will be the module name.) However, if there are command line flags or other arguments, that won't work. Once you're dealing with any complexity or uncertainty, you may want to use an arguments-parsing module like [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).